# How use setTimeout() with Singleton Module Pattern?

Tags: javascript

A public method wants to call a private method (passing some objects as arguments) after some period of time... How do we do it?

Wanted something like this:

```
var someClass = function(someObj) {
    var myPrivateMethod = function(someParam) {
        alert('i got ' + someObj + '!');
        if (someParam) alert('and i also got ' + someParam + '!');
    }

    var myDearPublicMethod = function(someParam) {
        if (someParam) {
            //call myPrivateMethod with setTimeOut so that it gets the someObj (and someParam if provided)
        } else {
            myPrivateMethod(someParam);
        }
    }

    return {
        somePublicMethod : myDearPublicMethod
    }
}

someClass('something').somePublicMethod('somethingELSE');
```

Answer (score 2):

Call an anonymous function that calls the function:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  localFunction(someObject);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what is your goal

```
if (someParam) {
            //call myPrivateMethod with setTimeOut so that it gets both someObj and someParam
        } else {
            myPrivateMethod(someParam);
        }
```

why in the else branch you call a method with someParam as a parameter if in that branch you just verified that someParam is false, null or undefined? what the real difference between branches?

Comment: if called with no argum (ie. someClass('something').somePublicMethod()) so straight to the private method; if called with an agrum, call the private method with setTimeout().